# Dynamic Refs in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

Can someone please help me understand dynamic refs in Vue3? I have a group of radio buttons and trying to return the value of the selected button. In the code below the same value is returned regardless of which button I click.

```
<script setup> 

const props = defineProps({       
    mealServices: Array,
});

const activeMealService = ref([])

const setActiveMealService = () => {
        console.log('meal id is ' + activeMealService)
};

</script>
```

```
<div v-for="mealService in mealServices" :key="mealService.id">
     <input  :ref="(el) => {activeMealService = mealService.meal_type_id}" 
             @click="setActiveMealService" type="radio" name="meal_type" 
             :id="mealService.meal_type_id" 
             :value="mealService.meal_type_id" 
             v-model="form.meal_type_id"/>
                                
     <label :for="mealService.meal_type_id">{{ mealService.meal_type.name }}</
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:ref="(el) => {activeMealService = mealService.meal_type_id}"` is called for every iteration, right?

I guess you're resetting the active meal in every render to the last meal.
You don't need a Template ref to get the current selected meal.

Try removing this line

Comment: How would i get the value of the current selected meal?

Comment: v-model should take care of that: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#radio

Comment: You could use a watcher too if you want to react to state changes